BLE Android Nordic
I'm writing an android application, using
no.nordicsemi.android:ble:2.3.1.
I connect to the sensor and write 49KB data to it.
Before recording, I set the desired interval (CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH 11.25 - 15ms) and MTU (247)
Next, I initiate the sending of files of 128, 232,240 bytes.
But the problem is that after sending, GATT sets me to interval 36 and not 12ms as I need. The sensor supports from 12 to 30ms.  I tried different versions of Android and the BLE version doesn't really make a difference either.If you need the code, I can show you some excerpts
Nothing helps, maybe there are some articles or something similar
UPD uploaded HCI log
https://dropmefiles.com/SEgPo
two files
Before sending all data I put this
requestConnectionPriority(ConnectionPriorityRequest.CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH)
.done(device -> Log.e("BleControlManager", "Interval request sent"))
.fail((device, status) -> Log.e("BleControlManager", "Failed to send Interval request: " + status))
.enqueue();
requestMtu(247)
.done(device -> Log.e("BleControlManager", "MTU request sent "))
.fail((device, status) -> Log.e("BleControlManager", "Failed to send MTU request: " + status))
.enqueue();
Then I receive a log from Gatt
2024-04-17 15:03:59.776 18358-18412 BluetoothGatt           com.example.bluetoothcontrol         D  onConfigureMTU() - Device=38:3B:26:7E:76:9B mtu=247 status=0
2024-04-17 15:03:59.910 18358-18412 BluetoothGatt           com.example.bluetoothcontrol         D  onConnectionUpdated() - Device=38:3B:26:7E:76:9B interval=12 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
Then several packets pass through to the device, and then this happens:
2024-04-17 15:04:00.405 18358-18412 BluetoothGatt           com.example.bluetoothcontrol         D  onConnectionUpdated() - Device=38:3B:26:7E:76:9B interval=36 latency=0 timeout=100 status=0
The log shows that after sending the packet, the interval changes without my participation
1704    330.000533  SamsungElect_3a:0a:01 (Galaxy A7 (2018))    JiangsuQinhe_7e:76:9b (SatelliteOnline0000) ATT 12  Sent Exchange MTU Request, Client Rx MTU: 247
1703    329.798134  controller  host    HCI_EVT 7   Rcvd Command Status (LE Connection Update)
1705    330.014861  controller  host    HCI_EVT 8   Rcvd Number of Completed Packets
1706    330.059797  JiangsuQinhe_7e:76:9b (SatelliteOnline0000) SamsungElect_3a:0a:01 (Galaxy A7 (2018))    ATT 12  Rcvd Exchange MTU Response, Server Rx MTU: 255
1707    330.060311  host    controller  HCI_CMD 10  Sent LE Set Data Length
1708    330.064660  controller  host    HCI_EVT 9   Rcvd Command Complete (LE Set Data Length)
1762    330.616503  controller  host    HCI_EVT 8   Rcvd Number of Completed Packets
1763    330.616628  SamsungElect_3a:0a:01 (Galaxy A7 (2018))    JiangsuQinhe_7e:76:9b (SatelliteOnline0000) L2CAP   15  Sent Connection Parameter Update Response (Accepted)
1764    330.617120  host    controller  HCI_CMD 18  Sent LE Connection Update
1765    330.617907  controller  host    HCI_EVT 7   Rcvd Command Status (LE Connection Update)
1766    330.630105  JiangsuQinhe_7e:76:9b (SatelliteOnline0000) SamsungElect_3a:0a:01 (Galaxy A7 (2018))    ATT 10  Rcvd Write Response, Handle: 0x0013 (Nordic UART Service: Nordic UART Rx: Client Characteristic Configuration)

HCI log or BLE sniffer log would be good.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Emil Hello, I uploaded two log files

Your log files seem empty? Make sure you can open the hci log file in e.g. Wireshark.

@Emil
https://dropmefiles.com/SEgPo
uploaded two log files

@Emil I think this is HCI problem here logs https://dropmefiles.com/SEgPo
